# Flickering line after updating ubuntu 11.10

Tags: screen

I just  bought a new Dell Vostro 2520 pre-installed with Ubuntu 11.10.
All was fine until I updated the OS. Since then, I have this flickering line at the top of my screen and it won't go after rebooting or changing the screen resolution. 
It gets really annoying.

I don't know which update did this.
I tried reinstalling the image from Dell, and it worked fine until I applied the updates. 
I tried to take a screen shot but it does not show. The line seems to be outside the desktop area.

Help please... Thanks!